Thunderbird - unread email count notification dot on dock not working correctly
I noticed that upon receiving new emails in Thunderbird, the Ubuntu Dock icon shows a green unread notification dot - great. However, when I read the email, the notification dot never changes or goes away, it just always stays at the previous count.
Also I noticed that if you start Thunderbird with say 5 unread emails the dock icon does not show any notification dot count. So the dot only seems to be shown or update on receiving new emails but nothing else.
I could not see anything reported in Bugzilla and wondered if anyone else has noticed this problem? Not sure if a Thunderbird issue or a Ubuntu dock issue.
I have a new clean installation of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and Snap install of Thunderbird (128.0esr). Can't see any config options regarding notification dots.

https://www-archive.mozilla.org/support/thunderbird/bugs

There is a now locked discussion on Mozzila Forums that refers to your issue. The final post suggests that this has been running for some time. I would suggest it is a TB issue, not Ubuntu specific. I use Betterbird on Debian 12 (a Flatpak v115.14.0-bb31) and don't see this issue, only a dot against the icon when new mails are present.

@graham, thanks, although the forum post is from 18 years ago! Maybe I will give Betterbird a try, not heard of that before.

I use it all the time now. You'll need to install Flatpaks of course - I don't think it's available as a Snap. A simple tip if I may. go to the hamburger menu in TB and select Tools then export your email accounts and then follow the same menu options in BB and import them to BB. Will save you a ton of time.

Just to add, TB and BB can co-exist on the same system. I have them both on my instance just that I only use BB now.

Actually, just found a recent bug report which sounds like it could be the same although this bug report is on Windows: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1911468

basically then, you have answered your own question. In BB (perhaps also in TB) under settings > Incoming Mails there is an option to show a tray icon for unread messages.

The indicator seems to show the number of system notifications, not the number of unread mail. See this comment on the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/2015674
